# create Dictionary class

Tags: ios, swift

I am coding a Swift class that builds a dictionary when instantiating it, plus the possibility of adding pairs of key - value, but once done the problem is I can not access the individual pairs I add, so there must be a problem somewhere I can not detect, please help

```
class MyDictionary {

var dictionary = ["":""]

init() {
}

func addPair(key: String, value: String) {
    //dictionary["key"] = "value"
    dictionary.updateValue(value, forKey: key)
}
```

}

```
// just to compare... this one works
    var dict = ["one": "abc"]
    dict["two"] = "efg"
    print(dict["two"]!)

    let myDictionary = MyDictionary()
    myDictionary.addPair(key: "key1", value: "value1")
    print(myDictionary)

    //print(myDictionary["key1"])  //Does not work
```

Comment: dictionary["key"] = "value" this will work.

Comment: It should not work because myDictionary is Class type not just a Swift Dictionary

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
print(myDictionary["key1"])
```

To

```
print(myDictionary.dictionary["key1"])
```

Answer (score 1):

I a assuming you want to create a custom dictionary, because you'd like to check (maybe in future) if the values to be added as as a key-pair are acceptable or so.

Anyway, if you want to have a custom dictionary class to act as a wrapper over the system Dictionary class, I'd advice to make the dictionary `property` private (so no outsiders can access and modify it directly), and add an additional method for getting the value for a key (if such key exists):

```
class MyDictionary {

    private var dictionary = ["":""]

    init() {
    }

    func addPair(key: String, value: String) {
        dictionary.updateValue(value, forKey: key)
    }

    func valueForKey(_ key: String) -> String? {
        if let valueForKey = dictionary[key] {
            return valueForKey
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

This is how would you use it:

```
let myDictionary = MyDictionary()
myDictionary.addPair(key: "key1", value: "value1")

if let valueForKey = myDictionary.valueForKey("key1") {
    print(valueForKey)
}
```

If you really want to get the value the way you mentioned it's not working, you'll need to implement a `subscript`, because MyDictionary is a custom class and does not have one yet:

```
class MyDictionary {

    private var dictionary = ["":""]

    /* more code */

    func valueForKey(_ key: String) -> String? {
        if let valueForKey = dictionary[key] {
            return valueForKey
        }
        return nil
    }

    subscript(_ key: String) -> String? {
        get {
            return valueForKey(key)
        }
    }
}
```

This is how would you use the subscript:

```
let myDictionary = MyDictionary()
myDictionary.addPair(key: "key1", value: "value1")

if let valueForKey = myDictionary["key1"] {
    print(valueForKey)
    print(myDictionary["key1"]!)
}
```

Note that `myDictionary["key1"]` returns an `Optional String`, or `String?`, therefore you'd have to force unwrap the value in order for the `print()` method not to complain. Since we do it inside the `if let` statement - we know `myDictionary["key1"]` is not nil, and `myDictionary["key1"]!` must be some valid String object.

See more here: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Subscripts.html

Answer (score 0):

To be able to use your syntax add key subscription support (getter and setter).

```
class MyDictionary {

    var dictionary = ["":""]

    init() {
    }

    func addPair(key: String, value: String) {
        dictionary.updateValue(value, forKey: key)
    }

    subscript(_ key: String) -> String? {
        get { return dictionary[key] }
        set { dictionary[key] = newValue }
    }
}

let myDictionary = MyDictionary()
myDictionary.addPair(key: "key1", value: "value1")
print(myDictionary["key1"]!)
```

---

You could extend the class as generic to use it with different types. The subscription setter makes `addPair` even redundant.

```
class MyDictionary<K : Hashable, V> {

    var dictionary = [K:V]()

    subscript(_ key: K) -> V? {
        get { return dictionary[key] }
        set { dictionary[key] = newValue }
    }
}

let myDictionary = MyDictionary<String,String>()
myDictionary["key1"] = "value1"   
print(myDictionary["key1"]!)
```